# Determine daylight saving time for US ZoneIds in Java

Tags: java, timezone, dst, java-time

I need to find out whether an Instant is in DST or not. I would expect it to work like that:

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of("America/New_York");
ZoneRules zr = z.getRules();
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone(z);

Instant summer = ZonedDateTime.of(2018, 5, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, z).toInstant();
Instant winter = ZonedDateTime.of(2018, 11, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, z).toInstant();

System.out.println("ZoneRules winter: " + zr.isDaylightSavings(winter));
System.out.println("ZoneRules summer: " + zr.isDaylightSavings(summer));
System.out.println("TimeZone winter: " + tz.inDaylightTime(Date.from(winter)));
System.out.println("TimeZone summer: " + tz.inDaylightTime(Date.from(summer)));
```

but my output for "America/New_York" and other US timezones is always:

```
ZoneRules winter: true
ZoneRules summer: true
TimeZone winter: true
TimeZone summer: true
```

ZoneRules.getOffset() also always returns the same value.

However, I don't see the same behaviour when working with European timezones. With `ZoneId.of("Europe/London")` or `ZoneId.of("Europe/Amsterdam")` I am getting the expected result:

```
ZoneRules winter: false
ZoneRules summer: true
TimeZone winter: false
TimeZone summer: true
```

What am I missing?

Here is some [example code on ideone](https://ideone.com/MKpmxG).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `winter` variable is equivalent to **November 1<sup>st</sup> 2018 in New York**. But in 2018, in New York timezone, [DST ends in November 4<sup>th</sup>](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/usa/new-york?year=2018), so the `winter` variable is still in DST.

You can check when the next transition will be using the `nextTransition` method:

```
System.out.println(zr.nextTransition(winter));
```

This will print:

> Transition[Overlap at **2018-11-04**T02:00-04:00 to -05:00]

Meaning that in November 4<sup>th</sup>, at 2 AM, clocks will be set 1 hour back (the "fall back" part of "spring forward/fall back rule"), and the offset will be changed from `-04:00` to  `-05:00`.

You can check that by creating the equivalent `Instant`:

```
// November 4th, at 02:02 AM (after DST transition)
Instant winter = ZonedDateTime.of(2018, 11, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, z).toInstant();
System.out.println(zr.isDaylightSavings(winter)); // false
```

---

Another way to check the transition dates is to loop through the transtions provided by the `ZoneRules`:

```
zr.getTransitions().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Some zones don't have specific transitions for each year (that's the case of `America/New_York`), but instead they have transition rules (such as "DST starts at the third Sunday of October"), so if you don't find a transition for a specific year using the `getTransitions()` method, you can check the transition rules:

```
zr.getTransitionRules().forEach(r -> System.out.println(r.createTransition(2018)));
```

For `America/New_York`, the output is:

> Transition[Gap at 2018-03-11T02:00-05:00 to -04:00]
>   Transition[Overlap at **2018-11-04**T02:00-04:00 to -05:00]

Comment: Thank you so much! Actually I wanted to pick December 1, but the month in ZonedDateTime is not 0-based anymore (like it was in java.util.Date and Calendar).

Comment: Unfortunately, it's still a common mistake. I really hate this 0-based month thing...